# Setting angular grid height to match content

Tags: html, css, angular

In my html I have the following:

```
<div class="layout-container">
          <div class="rhi-grid-wrapper" style="width: 40%;">
            <igx-grid *ngIf="!setUp" [data]="factoredEstimateTemplateList" [rowStyles]="rowStyles" style=" overflow-y: auto;">
              <igx-column field="name" header="Name" [width]="'50%'"></igx-column>
              <igx-column field="total" header="Total" [width]="'50%'" dataType="number">
                <ng-template igxCell let-val>
                  <div class="cell__inner">
                      {{ val | number: '1.0-0' }}
                  </div>
                </ng-template>
              </igx-column>
            </igx-grid>
          </div>

          <div *ngIf="!setUp && chartData && chartData.length!=0" class="chart-container" height="25%" style="padding-top: 1rem; width: 60%;">
            <igx-category-chart *ngIf="darkTheme;else lightThemeChart"
            name="chart" #chart chartType="Column" [dataSource]="chartData" [legend]="" width="900px" height="100%"
            yAxisMinimumValue="0" yAxisTitle="Total" yAxisTitleLeftMargin="10" yAxisTitleRightMargin="5" yAxisLabelLeftMargin="0" yAxisLabelTextColor="#FFFFFF" yAxisTitleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            xAxisGap="1" xAxisLabelTextColor= "#FFFFFF"
            isHorizontalZoomEnabled="false" isVerticalZoomEnabled="false" isCategoryHighlightingEnabled="true"
            highlightingMode="FadeOthersSpecific" highlightingBehavior="NearestItemsAndSeries" crosshairsDisplayMode="None"
            brushes="#AD4699"
            style="margin:auto">
            </igx-category-chart>

            <ng-template #lightThemeChart>
              <igx-category-chart
              name="chart" #chart chartType="Column" [dataSource]="chartData" [legend]="" width="900px" height="100%"
              yAxisMinimumValue="0" yAxisTitle="Total" yAxisTitleLeftMargin="10" yAxisTitleRightMargin="5" yAxisLabelLeftMargin="0" yAxisLabelTextColor="#000000" yAxisTitleTextColor="#000000"
              xAxisGap="1" xAxisLabelTextColor= "#000000"
              isHorizontalZoomEnabled="false" isVerticalZoomEnabled="false" isCategoryHighlightingEnabled="true"
              highlightingMode="FadeOthersSpecific" highlightingBehavior="NearestItemsAndSeries" crosshairsDisplayMode="None"
              brushes="#AD4699"
              style="margin:auto">
              </igx-category-chart>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
        </div>
```

the css for layout-container is like so:

```
.layout-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50%;
}
```

what I am trying to do with the grid is to make the height match the content within it and then if the height to exceed 100% then it would add the scroll bar. At the moment though, the height is just getting set to 100% even though the amount of rows within do not make up 100%. I have tried setting the height to auto but that just seems to make the height of the first row within it. How can I fix this? I'm not sure what else I could try here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great question!

If you add [height]="'auto'" to the igx-grid, the grid will automatically resize to content height and if it goes beyond the div height, the scrollbar will appear:

```
 <igx-grid *ngIf="!setUp" [data]="factoredEstimateTemplateList" [height]="'auto'" [rowStyles]="rowStyles">
```